# Height of Google Native Ads in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a native ad using google_mobile_ads plugin. The size of the native ad varies depending on how many lines there are in the headline and the body. However the AdWidget needs to be surrounded by a Container and needs height attribute as AdWidget has infinite height. How do I solve this. I want the Ad to be fluid. Is there a way for the native code to communicate back the height that can be used in flutter

This is the example from https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/native

````
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: adWidget,
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
);```
````

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native/templates#:~:text=The%20medium%20template%20is%20meant,high%20by%20355%20points%20wide.